# How to make regex to Put semi-unstructured data in table or dataframe Python?

Tags: python, string, extract

This is the Data which need to be put in a table or dataframe

```
1.4 (iii) Imperial Energy Nord Limited Cyprus 100% 100% Audited
1.4 (iv) Biancus Holdings Limited Cyprus 100% 100% Audited
1.4 (v) Redcliffe Holdings Limited Cyprus 100% 100% Auditedd341
2 Mangalore Refinery and Petrochemicals Ltd. (MRPL)
(Note no.4(a)&(d))India 80.94% 80.72% Audited
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating *six* columns, shown by example as CSV as follows using the first row of sample data:

```
1.4, iii, Imperial Energy Nord Limited Cyprus, 100%, 100%, Audited
```

You may load this data into a single column.  Then create 6 columns and populate them using `str.extract`:

```py
df[["major", "minor", "company", "pct1", "pct2", "status"]] =
    df["text"].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) \((.*?)\) (.*?)(?= \d+(?:\.\d+)?%) (\d+(?:\.\d+)?%) (\d+(?:\.\d+)?%) (\w+)')
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UhoZbe/1) showing that the regex logic is working.

Comment: How to make edits in the regex if the roman number is optional and not present in every row?

Comment: @timBiegelesien??